# In Wickedpicker how to set my time like "08:00 AM"?

Tags: jquery, timepicker, wickedpicker

I want timepicker with UI like mobile device.
I was trying different plugins. I got "Wickedpicker" close to what i need.

In this I am not able to populate my default time in edit page like "08:30 AM" or "01:30 PM".

It is always showing current time.

These are options for plugin:

```
var options = { 
   now: "12:35", //hh:mm 24 hour format only, defaults to current time
   twentyFour: false, //Display 24 hour format, defaults to false
   upArrow: 'wickedpicker__controls__control-up', //The up arrow class selector to use, for custom CSS
   downArrow: 'wickedpicker__controls__control-down', //The down arrow class selector to use, for custom CSS
   close: 'wickedpicker__close', //The close class selector to use, for custom CSS
   hoverState: 'hover-state', //The hover state class to use, for custom CSS
   title: 'Timepicker', //The Wickedpicker's title,
   showSeconds: false, //Whether or not to show seconds,
   secondsInterval: 1, //Change interval for seconds, defaults to 1
   , minutesInterval: 1, //Change interval for minutes, defaults to 1
   beforeShow: null, //A function to be called before the Wickedpicker is shown
   show: null, //A function to be called when the Wickedpicker is shown
   clearable: false, //Make the picker's input clearable (has clickable "x")
};
```

Ref Link : https://ericjgagnon.github.io/wickedpicker/

I have tried by changing option "now" to false and remove it but still same thing happen.

It will be helfull if anyone can also give link to similar jquery plugin for time picker with time limit set.

Answer (score 4):

In the current version (*v0.4.1*) there isn't a way to update the time programatically, so I've modified the plugin.

Here's how to use it:

```
var myPicker = $('.timepicker').wickedpicker(options);

// set time to 2pm
myPicker.wickedpicker('setTime', 0, "14:00"); // 0 is the index of the timepicker. Use 0 if only one is present
```

Demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FDhlj3dS6bOWzcxC0fr8?p=preview

```
/**
 * wickedpicker v0.4.1 - A simple jQuery timepicker.
 * Copyright (c) 2015-2016 Eric Gagnon - http://github.com/wickedRidge/wickedpicker
 * License: MIT
 * 
 * 31/07/17 Modified by K Scandrett to allow changing the time.
 * Example:
 *    var options = {now: "12:35"};
 *    var myPicker = $('.timepicker').wickedpicker(options);
 * 
 *    myPicker.wickedpicker('setTime', 0, "14:00"); // 0 is the index of the timepicker. Use 0 if only one
 */

(function ($, window, document) {

    "use strict";

    if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith != 'function') {
        /*
         * Checks if this string end ends with another string
         *
         * @param {string} the string to be checked
         *
         * @return {bool}
         */
        String.prototype.endsWith = function (string) {
            return string.length > 0 && this.substring(this.length - string.length, this.length) === string;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Returns if the user agent is mobile
     *
     * @return {bool}
     */
    var isMobile = function () {
        return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    };

    var today = new Date();

    var pluginName = "wickedpicker",
        defaults = {
            now: today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes(),
            twentyFour: false,
            upArrow: 'wickedpicker__controls__control-up',
            downArrow: 'wickedpicker__controls__control-down',
            close: 'wickedpicker__close',
            hoverState: 'hover-state',
            title: 'Timepicker',
            showSeconds: false,
            timeSeparator: ' : ',
            secondsInterval: 1,
            minutesInterval: 1,
            beforeShow: null,
            afterShow: null,
            show: null,
            clearable: false,
            closeOnClickOutside: true,
            onClickOutside: function() {},
        };

    /*
     * @param {object} The input object the timepicker is attached to.
     * @param {object} The object containing options
     */
    function Wickedpicker(element, options) {
        this.element = $(element);
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        this.element.addClass('hasWickedpicker');
        this.element.attr('onkeypress', 'return false;');
        this.element.attr('aria-showingpicker', 'false');
        this.createPicker();
        this.timepicker = $('.wickedpicker');
        this.up = $('.' + this.options.upArrow.split(/\s+/).join('.'));
        this.down = $('.' + this.options.downArrow.split(/\s+/).join('.'));
        this.separator = $('.wickedpicker__controls__control--separator');
        this.hoursElem = $('.wickedpicker__controls__control--hours');
        this.minutesElem = $('.wickedpicker__controls__control--minutes');
        this.secondsElem = $('.wickedpicker__controls__control--seconds');
        this.meridiemElem = $('.wickedpicker__controls__control--meridiem');
        this.close = $('.' + this.options.close.split(/\s+/).join('.'));

        //Create a new Date object based on the default or passing in now value
        var time = this.timeArrayFromString(this.options.now);
        this.options.now = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), time[0], time[1], time[2]);
        this.selectedHour = this.parseHours(this.options.now.getHours());
        this.selectedMin = this.parseSecMin(this.options.now.getMinutes());
        this.selectedSec = this.parseSecMin(this.options.now.getSeconds());
        this.selectedMeridiem = this.parseMeridiem(this.options.now.getHours());
        this.setHoverState();
        this.attach(element);
        this.setText(element);
    }

    $.extend(Wickedpicker.prototype, {

        /*
         * Show given input's timepicker
         *
         * @param {object} The input being clicked
         */
        showPicker: function (element) {
            //If there is a beforeShow function, then call it with the input calling the timepicker and the
            // timepicker itself
            if (typeof this.options.beforeShow === 'function') {
                this.options.beforeShow(element, this.timepicker);
            }
            var timepickerPos = $(element).offset();

            $(element).attr({'aria-showingpicker': 'true', 'tabindex': -1});
            this.setText(element);
            this.showHideMeridiemControl();
            if (this.getText(element) !== this.getTime()) {

                // Check meridiem 
                var text = this.getText(element);
                var meridiem = /\s\w\w$/.test(text) ? text.substr(-2, 2) : null;
                var inputTime = text.replace(/\s\w\w$/, '').split(this.options.timeSeparator);
                var newTime = {};
                newTime.hours = inputTime[0];
                newTime.minutes = inputTime[1];
                if (this.options.showSeconds) {
                    newTime.seconds = inputTime[2];
                    newTime.meridiem = meridiem;
                } else {
                    newTime.meridiem = meridiem;
                }
                this.setTime(newTime);
            }
            this.timepicker.css({
                'z-index': this.element.css('z-index') + 1,
                position: 'absolute',
                left: timepickerPos.left,
                top: timepickerPos.top + $(element)[0].offsetHeight
            }).show();
            //If there is a show function, then call it with the input calling the timepicker and the
            // timepicker itself
            if (typeof this.options.show === 'function') {
                this.options.show(element, this.timepicker);
            }

            this.handleTimeAdjustments(element);
        },

        /*
         * Hides the timepicker that is currently shown if it is not part of the timepicker
         *
         * @param {Object} The DOM object being clicked on the page
         * 
         * BeinnLora: added trigger function to call on closing/hiding timepicker. 
         */
        hideTimepicker: function (element) {
            this.timepicker.hide();
            if (typeof this.options.afterShow === 'function') {
                this.options.afterShow(element, this.timepicker);
            }
            var pickerHidden = {
                start: function () {
                    var setShowPickerFalse = $.Deferred();
                    $('[aria-showingpicker="true"]').attr('aria-showingpicker', 'false');
                    return setShowPickerFalse.promise();
                }
            };

            function setTabIndex(index) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('[aria-showingpicker="false"]').attr('tabindex', index);
                }, 400);
            }

            pickerHidden.start().then(setTabIndex(0));
        },

        /*
         * Create a new timepicker. A single timepicker per page
         */
        createPicker: function () {
            if ($('.wickedpicker').length === 0) {
                var picker = '<div class="wickedpicker"><p class="wickedpicker__title">' + this.options.title + '<span class="wickedpicker__close"></span></p><ul class="wickedpicker__controls"><li class="wickedpicker__controls__control"><span class="' + this.options.upArrow + '"></span><span class="wickedpicker__controls__control--hours" tabindex="-1">00</span><span class="' + this.options.downArrow + '"></span></li><li class="wickedpicker__controls__control--separator"><span class="wickedpicker__controls__control--separator-inner">:</span></li><li class="wickedpicker__controls__control"><span class="' + this.options.upArrow + '"></span><span class="wickedpicker__controls__control--minutes" tabindex="-1">00</span><span class="' + this.options.downArrow + '"></span></li>';
                if (this.options.showSeconds) {
                    picker += '<li class="wickedpicker__controls__control--separator"><span class="wickedpicker__controls__control--separator-inner">:</span></li><li class="wickedpicker__controls__control"><span class="' + this.options.upArrow + '"></span><span class="wickedpicker__controls__control--seconds" tabindex="-1">00</span><span class="' + this.options.downArrow + '"></span> </li>';
                }
                picker += '<li class="wickedpicker__controls__control"><span class="' + this.options.upArrow + '"></span><span class="wickedpicker__controls__control--meridiem" tabindex="-1">AM</span><span class="' + this.options.downArrow + '"></span></li></ul></div>';
                $('body').append(picker);
                this.attachKeyboardEvents();
            }
        },

        /*
         * Hides the meridiem control if this timepicker is a 24 hour clock
         */
        showHideMeridiemControl: function () {
            if (this.options.twentyFour === false) {
                $(this.meridiemElem).parent().show();
            }
            else {
                $(this.meridiemElem).parent().hide();
            }
        },

        /*
         * Hides the seconds control if this timepicker has showSeconds set to true
         */
        showHideSecondsControl: function () {
            if (this.options.showSeconds) {
                $(this.secondsElem).parent().show();
            }
            else {
                $(this.secondsElem).parent().hide();
            }
        },

        /*
         * Bind the click events to the input
         *
         * @param {object} The input element
         */
        attach: function (element) {
            var self = this;

            if (this.options.clearable) {
                self.makePickerInputClearable(element);
            }

            $(element).attr('tabindex', 0);
            $(element).on('click focus', function (event) {
                //Prevent multiple firings
                if ($(self.timepicker).is(':hidden')) {
                  self.showPicker($(this));
                  window.lastTimePickerControl = $(this); //Put the reference on this timepicker into global scope for unsing that in afterShow function
                  $(self.hoursElem).focus();
                }
            });


            //Handle click events for closing Wickedpicker
            var clickHandler = function (event) { //TODO: Fix double firing
                //Only fire the hide event when you have to
                if ($(self.timepicker).is(':visible')) {
                    //Clicking the X
                    if ($(event.target).is(self.close)) {
                      self.hideTimepicker(window.lastTimePickerControl);
                    } else if ($(event.target).closest(self.timepicker).length || $(event.target).closest($('.hasWickedpicker')).length) { //Clicking the Wickedpicker or one of it's inputs
                      event.stopPropagation();
                    } else {   //Everything else
                      if (typeof self.options.onClickOutside === 'function') {
                        self.options.onClickOutside();
                      }
                      else {
                        console.warn("Type of onClickOutside must be a function");
                      }

                      if (!self.options.closeOnClickOutside) {
                        return;
                      }
                      self.hideTimepicker(window.lastTimePickerControl);
                    }
                    window.lastTimePickerControl = null;
                }
            };
            $(document).off('click', clickHandler).on('click', clickHandler);
        },

        /**
         * Added keyboard functionality to improve usabil
         */
        attachKeyboardEvents: function () {
            $(document).on('keydown', $.proxy(function (event) {
                switch (event.keyCode) {
                    case 9:
                        if (event.target.className !== 'hasWickedpicker') {
                            $(this.close).trigger('click');
                        }
                        break;
                    case 27:
                        $(this.close).trigger('click');
                        break;
                    case 37: //Left arrow
                        if (event.target.className !== this.hoursElem[0].className) {
                            $(event.target).parent().prevAll('li').not(this.separator.selector).first().children()[1].focus();
                        } else {
                            $(event.target).parent().siblings(':last').children()[1].focus();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 39: //Right arrow
                        if (event.target.className !== this.meridiemElem[0].className) {
                            $(event.target).parent().nextAll('li').not(this.separator.selector).first().children()[1].focus();
                        } else {
                            $(event.target).parent().siblings(':first').children()[1].focus();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 38: //Up arrow
                        $(':focus').prev().trigger('click');
                        break;
                    case 40: //Down arrow
                        $(':focus').next().trigger('click');
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }, this));
        },

        /*
         * Set the time on the timepicker
         *
         * @param {object} The date being set
         */
        setTime: function (time) {
            this.setHours(time.hours);
            this.setMinutes(time.minutes);
            this.setMeridiem(time.meridiem);
            if (this.options.showSeconds) {
                this.setSeconds(time.seconds);
            }
        },

        /*
         * Get the time from the timepicker
         */
        getTime: function () {
            return [this.formatTime(this.getHours(), this.getMinutes(), this.getMeridiem(), this.getSeconds())];
        },

        /*
         * Set the timpicker's hour(s) value
         *
         * @param {string} hours
         */
        setHours: function (hours) {
            var hour = new Date();
            hour.setHours(hours);
            var hoursText = this.parseHours(hour.getHours());
            this.hoursElem.text(hoursText);
            this.selectedHour = hoursText;
        },

        /*
         * Get the hour(s) value from the timepicker
         *
         * @return {integer}
         */
        getHours: function () {
            var hours = new Date();
            hours.setHours(this.hoursElem.text());
            return hours.getHours();
        },

        /*
         * Returns the correct hour value based on the type of clock, 12 or 24 hour
         *
         * @param {integer} The hours value before parsing
         *
         * @return {string|integer}
         */
        parseHours: function (hours) {
            return (this.options.twentyFour === false) ? ((hours + 11) % 12) + 1 : (hours < 10) ? '0' + hours : hours;
        },

        /*
         * Sets the timpicker's minutes value
         *
         * @param {string} minutes
         */
        setMinutes: function (minutes) {
            var minute = new Date();
            minute.setMinutes(minutes);
            var minutesText = minute.getMinutes();
            var min = this.parseSecMin(minutesText);
            this.minutesElem.text(min);
            this.selectedMin = min;
        },

        /*
         * Get the minutes value from the timepicker
         *
         * @return {integer}
         */
        getMinutes: function () {
            var minutes = new Date();
            minutes.setMinutes(this.minutesElem.text());
            return minutes.getMinutes();
        },


        /*
         * Return a human-readable minutes/seconds value
         *
         * @param {string} value seconds or minutes
         *
         * @return {string|integer}
         */
        parseSecMin: function (value) {
            return ((value < 10) ? '0' : '') + value;
        },

        /*
         * Set the timepicker's meridiem value, AM or PM
         *
         * @param {string} The new meridiem
         */
        setMeridiem: function (inputMeridiem) {
            var newMeridiem = '';
            if (inputMeridiem === undefined) {
                var meridiem = this.getMeridiem();
                newMeridiem = (meridiem === 'PM') ? 'AM' : 'PM';
            } else {
                newMeridiem = inputMeridiem;
            }
            this.meridiemElem.text(newMeridiem);
            this.selectedMeridiem = newMeridiem;
        },

        /*
         * Get the timepicker's meridiem value, AM or PM
         *
         * @return {string}
         */
        getMeridiem: function () {
            return this.meridiemElem.text();
        },

        /*
         * Set the timepicker's seconds value
         *
         * @param {string} seconds
         */
        setSeconds: function (seconds) {
            var second = new Date();
            second.setSeconds(seconds);
            var secondsText = second.getSeconds();
            var sec = this.parseSecMin(secondsText);
            this.secondsElem.text(sec);
            this.selectedSec = sec;
        },

        /*
         * Get the timepicker's seconds value
         *
         * return {string}
         */
        getSeconds: function () {
            var seconds = new Date();
            seconds.setSeconds(this.secondsElem.text());
            return seconds.getSeconds();
        },

        /*
         * Get the correct meridiem based on the hours given
         *
         * @param {string|integer} hours
         *
         * @return {string}
         */
        parseMeridiem: function (hours) {
            return (hours > 11) ? 'PM' : 'AM';
        },

        /*
         * Handles time incrementing and decrementing and passes
         * the operator, '+' or '-', the input to be set after the change
         * and the current arrow clicked, to decipher if hours, ninutes, or meridiem.
         *
         * @param {object} The input element
         */
        handleTimeAdjustments: function (element) {
            var timeOut = 0;
            //Click and click and hold timepicker incrementer and decrementer
            $(this.up).add(this.down).off('mousedown click touchstart').on('mousedown click', {
                'Wickedpicker': this,
                'input': element
            }, function (event) {
                if(event.which!=1) return false;
                var operator = (this.className.indexOf('up') > -1) ? '+' : '-';
                var passedData = event.data;
                if (event.type == 'mousedown') {
                    timeOut = setInterval($.proxy(function (args) {
                        args.Wickedpicker.changeValue(operator, args.input, this);
                    }, this, {'Wickedpicker': passedData.Wickedpicker, 'input': passedData.input}), 200);
                } else {
                    passedData.Wickedpicker.changeValue(operator, passedData.input, this);
                }
            }).bind('mouseup touchend', function () {
                clearInterval(timeOut);
            });
        },

        /*
         * Change the timepicker's time base on what is clicked
         *
         * @param {string} The + or - operator
         * @param {object} The timepicker's associated input to be set post change
         * @param {object} The DOM arrow object clicked, determines if it is hours,
         * minutes, or meridiem base on the operator and its siblings
         */
        changeValue: function (operator, input, clicked) {
            var target = (operator === '+') ? clicked.nextSibling : clicked.previousSibling;
            var targetClass = $(target).attr('class');
            if (targetClass.endsWith('hours')) {
                this.setHours(eval(this.getHours() + operator + 1));
            } else if (targetClass.endsWith('minutes')) {
                this.setMinutes(eval(this.getMinutes() + operator + this.options.minutesInterval));
            } else if (targetClass.endsWith('seconds')) {
                this.setSeconds(eval(this.getSeconds() + operator + this.options.secondsInterval));
            } else {
                this.setMeridiem();
            }
            this.setText(input);
        },


        /*
         * Sets the give input's text to the current timepicker's time
         *
         * @param {object} The input element
         */
        setText: function (input) {
            $(input).val(this.formatTime(this.selectedHour, this.selectedMin, this.selectedMeridiem, this.selectedSec)).change();
        },

        /*
         * Get the given input's value
         *
         * @param {object} The input element
         *
         * @return {string}
         */
        getText: function (input) {
            return $(input).val();
        },

        /*
         * Returns the correct time format as a string
         *
         * @param {string} hour
         * @param {string} minutes
         * @param {string} meridiem
         *
         * @return {string}
         */
        formatTime: function (hour, min, meridiem, seconds) {
            var formattedTime = hour + this.options.timeSeparator + min;
            if (this.options.twentyFour) {
                formattedTime = hour + this.options.timeSeparator  + min;
            }
            if (this.options.showSeconds) {
                formattedTime += this.options.timeSeparator  + seconds;
            }
            if (this.options.twentyFour === false) {
                formattedTime += ' ' + meridiem;
            }
            return formattedTime;
        },

        /**
         *  Apply the hover class to the arrows and close icon fonts
         */
        setHoverState: function () {
            var self = this;
            if (!isMobile()) {
                $(this.up).add(this.down).add(this.close).hover(function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass(self.options.hoverState);
                });
            }
        },

        /**
         * Wrapping the given input field with the clearable container
         * , add a span that will contain the x, and bind the clear
         * input event to the span
         *
         * @param input
         */
        makePickerInputClearable: function(input) {
            $(input).wrap('<div class="clearable-picker"></div>').after('<span data-clear-picker>&times;</span>');

            //When the x is clicked, clear its sibling input field
            $('[data-clear-picker]').on('click', function(event) {
               $(this).siblings('.hasWickedpicker').val('');
            });
        },

        /**
         * Convert the options time string format
         * to an array
         *
         * returns => [hours, minutes, seconds]
         *
         * @param stringTime
         * @returns {*}
         */
        timeArrayFromString: function (stringTime) {
            if (stringTime.length) {
                var time = stringTime.split(':');
                time[2] = (time.length < 3) ? '00' : time[2];
                return time;
            }
            return false;
        },

        //public functions
        /*
         * Returns the requested input element's value
         */
        _time: function () {
            var inputValue = $(this.element).val();
            return (inputValue === '') ? this.formatTime(this.selectedHour, this.selectedMin, this.selectedMeridiem, this.selectedSec) : inputValue;
        },
        /* KS Added this function */
        _setTime: function (stringTime) {

            this.options.now = stringTime;

            var time = this.timeArrayFromString(this.options.now);
            this.options.now = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), time[0], time[1], time[2]);
            this.selectedHour = this.parseHours(this.options.now.getHours());
            this.selectedMin = this.parseSecMin(this.options.now.getMinutes());
            this.selectedSec = this.parseSecMin(this.options.now.getSeconds());
            this.selectedMeridiem = this.parseMeridiem(this.options.now.getHours());              

            this.setText(this.element);

            var inputValue = $(this.element).val();
            return (inputValue === '') ? this.formatTime(this.selectedHour, this.selectedMin, this.selectedMeridiem, this.selectedSec) : inputValue;
        },
        _hide: function() {
            this.hideTimepicker(this.element);
        }
    });

    //optional index if multiple inputs share the same class
    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options, index, time) {
        if (!$.isFunction(Wickedpicker.prototype['_' + options])) {
            return this.each(function () {
                if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                    $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Wickedpicker(this, options));
                }
            });
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass('hasWickedpicker')) {
            /* KS Added this check for 'setTime' */
            if (options === "setTime") {
              if (index !== undefined) {
                  return $.data($(this)[index], 'plugin_' + pluginName)['_setTime'](time);
              }
              else {
                  return $.data($(this)[0], 'plugin_' + pluginName)['_setTime'](time);
              }
            } 
            else
            {
              if (index !== undefined) {
                  return $.data($(this)[index], 'plugin_' + pluginName)['_' + options]();
              }
              else {
                  return $.data($(this)[0], 'plugin_' + pluginName)['_' + options]();
              }
            }
        }
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is that I have initiate the picker once on a page. Then In popup I will get dynamic entry of time it can be any time so I need to re-initiate options for every popup?

Comment: I've changed the plugin to allow setting the time. There's no way to do it without code changes.

Comment: If I change Options to contain "twentyFour: true" wickedpicker stops working. When clicking such an edit field, the opening form shows "NaN : NaN".

Comment: Thanks for the edit! It's working like a charm for me. I instanciate the timepicker on pageload and I change the time using your setTime function.

Comment: @ralfiii, it's a very old thread. Still posting if it will be useful for others as it was for me today. I have made a small change to @K Scandrett's js file in the line number 122.
var inputTime;
                if(meridiem!=null){
                inputTime = text.replace(/\s\w\w$/, '').split(this.options.timeSeparator);
                }
                else{
                    inputTime = text.split(this.options.timeSeparator);
                }

Answer (score 0):

The option **now** should be set to the **required time**.  When initializing the input element as a wickedpicker you would need to pass in the required time in 24hour format i.e. "08:00", "13:30", "20:50" etc:

```
$('.timepicker').wickedpicker({now:"12:34"});
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

**wickedpicker.js** default ↓

```
var pluginName = "wickedpicker",
    defaults = {
        now: today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes(),
        twentyFour: false,
        upArrow: 'fas fa-caret-up',
        downArrow: 'fas fa-caret-down',
        close: 'wickedpicker__close',
        hoverState: 'hover-state',
        title: 'Timepicker',
        showSeconds: false,
        timeSeparator: ' : ', //this
        secondsInterval: 1,
        minutesInterval: 1,
        beforeShow: null,
        afterShow: null,
        show: null,
        clearable: false,
        closeOnClickOutside: true,
        onClickOutside: function() {},
    };
```

result 12 : 35 PM

--

You have to change this.

```
timeSeparator: ':', //change
```

without Word spacing

Answer (score 0):

**If you have not initialized the element with wickedpicker**

simply set the time with the now option as show in the other answers here

```
$('.timepicker').wickedpicker({now:"20:00"}); //initialize the time to 8pm
```

**Updating time for an element**

if an element is already been initialized with the plugin, the plugin does not allow you to update the time. But this can be done by replacing the element with a clone and setting up the plugin on the cloned element

```
function replaceWithClone(el){
   var newEl = el.cloneNode(false);
   while (el.hasChildNodes()) newEl.appendChild(el.firstChild);
   el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);
}



$('#timepicker').wickedpicker({now:"20:00"}); //time set to 8pm
$('#timepicker').val(''); //clear time
replaceWithClone($('.timepicker').get()); //replace the element with its clone
$('.timepicker').wickedpicker({now:"22:00"}); //time now set to 10pm
```